# How to put tooltips depending on togglebutton's state, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, togglebutton

I created a toggle button in WPF. Each state is represented by an image.
It looks like that:

```
<ToggleButton Click="ButtonEnable_Click" x:Name="ButtonEnable" Width="36" Height="36" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true" >
    <ToggleButton.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="imgNormal" UriSource="/Project;component/Resources/images/Image-active.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="imgChecked"  UriSource="/Project;component/Resources/images/Image-inactive.png"/>
    </ToggleButton.Resources>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Image x:Name="PART_Image"  Source="{StaticResource imgNormal}"/>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource imgChecked}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource imgNormal}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

And everything works fine.
But i want to create a tooltip for each state of my togglebutton.
One "Active, blabla".
And the other "Inactive blabla".
And my software has to be localized, so the text of the tooltip is based on a ressource (en, fr, de, etc).

From what i saw, i am pretty sure it's a simple keyword or something... But i don't know what keyword, and where i have to put it...

Thanks a lot.
Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**U**se `Style` something like:

```
 <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Static local:MainWindow.Tooltip1}"/>
 </Trigger>
 <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Static local:MainWindow.Tooltip2}"/>
 </Trigger>
```

**Property:** Use *`CLR property`* to get values from Resource file

```
private static string tooltip1;

    public static string Tooltip1
    {
        get 
        {
            if (tooltip1 == null)
            {
                tooltip1 = "";//get this value form Resources
            }
            return tooltip1; 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set the Tooltip property

```
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Active"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value=""></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
```